# Subset of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can I assume the following:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $S \subset R $ closed under multiplication. If $x \notin S$ then $\langle x \rangle\cap S =\emptyset $ ?

Comment: why do you think so... could you write a small outline/guess what ever you feel comfortable..

Comment: I've got a counter example by someone here.
I guess my way to proof a question I've been given is wrong.
I'll write the question in a new post.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counter-example: $R=\mathbb{Z}, S=\mathbb{N},x=-1$.

Comment: Or just $S=\{1\}$ and $R$ any ring of characteristic not $2$.

Comment: @lhf: Yes, of course.